# Extend XMLHttpRequest in Scala.js

Tags: xmlhttprequest, scala.js

I'm extending XMLHttpRequest in Scala.js:

```
class ReasonerHttpRequest(val reasonerId: String) extends XMLHttpRequest {}
```

Then, I try to create:

```
val http = new ReasonerHttpRequest(reasonerId)
```

This result in the following error:

```
TypeError: $g.ReasonerHttpRequest is not a constructor
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any compiler warning? If using Scala.js 0.6.x, did you add `scalacOptions += "-P:scalajs:sjsDefinedByDefault"` to your project's `settings` in sbt?

Comment: @sjrd That does not seem to make a difference. Anyway, my understanding is that this should not be necessary starting 0.6.17, and I'm using 0.6.23, the latest stable.

Comment: @sjrd Actually, it made one difference. The error now is:

     "TypeError: Constructor XMLHttpRequest requires 'new'"

which makes no sense to me as I did use `new`.

Comment: It's probably because you cannot extend `XMLHttpRequest` with an ES 5.1 function+prototype. Try emitting ES 2015 code from Scala.js using `scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withESFeatures(_.withUseECMAScript2015(true)) }`. Note that this requires that your target browsers support ES 2015.